# "abort: No module named selectors!" when Pushing Mercurial repository to Git repository

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket

I am trying to convert Hg repository to Git repository. Both are private repository.

I have followed these steps ([reference](http://arr.gr/blog/2011/10/bitbucket-converting-hg-repositories-to-git/)):

- Step 1: Set up your repositories
- Step 2: Install the Mercurial hggit plugin
- Step 3: Push your code into your Git repository
- Step 4: Switch your local repository to use Git

I have installed the prerequisites also viz. hg-git plugin and updated the .hgrc file of the repository that needs to convert.

Error coming while pushing the repository( hg push [Git repo path] ) is "abort: No module named selectors!"

I have used --traceback option, please find the log below:

```
E:\BK_Hg\testHg>hg push --traceback https://CJbipin@bitbucket.org/CJbipin/testgit2.git
pushing to https://CJbipin@bitbucket.org/CJbipin/testgit2.git
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 161, in callcatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 344, in _runcatchfunc
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 984, in _dispatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 730, in runcommand
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 992, in _runcommand
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 981, in <lambda>
File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1528, in check
File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 4369, in push
File "E:/hg-git\hggit\util.py", line 60, in inner
File "E:/hg-git\hggit\__init__.py", line 414, in exchangepush
File "E:/hg-git\hggit\git_handler.py", line 405, in push
File "E:/hg-git\hggit\git_handler.py", line 1063, in upload_pack
File "E:/hg-git\hggit\git_handler.py", line 1749, in get_transport_and_path
File "dulwich\client.pyo", line 1330, in __init__
File "dulwich\client.pyo", line 1304, in default_urllib3_manager
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 167, in _demandimport
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
File "urllib3\__init__.pyo", line 8, in <module>
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 243, in _demandimport
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
File "urllib3\connectionpool.pyo", line 29, in <module>
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 243, in _demandimport
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
File "urllib3\connection.pyo", line 39, in <module>
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 243, in _demandimport
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
File "urllib3\util\__init__.pyo", line 3, in <module>
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 243, in _demandimport
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
File "urllib3\util\connection.pyo", line 3, in <module>
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 243, in _demandimport
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
File "urllib3\util\wait.pyo", line 1, in <module>
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 243, in _demandimport
File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyo", line 41, in _hgextimport
ImportError: No module named selectors
abort: No module named selectors!
```

regards
Bipin Kumar

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/5140/hg-git-abort-no-module-named-selectors

Comment: Run `hg-git` with Python 3.

Comment: i have tried with python also, version 3.7.3 but same error is coming.

Comment: Patch from comments in issue, noted by @phd, helped me with GIt-repos (I could cloneit without errors). Win10x64, THG 4.9.1

Answer (score 2):

Because even in released THG 5.0.2 bundled hg-git sill have the same problem:

### THG 5 solutions in details, step-by-step

**Lazy fast way**

- Download patched full `lib` for THG 4.9.1 from [comment in BB's issue](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/5140/hg-git-abort-no-module-named-selectors#comment-52063826)
- Replace `dulwich` + `urllib3` in your THG's library archive by patched version from the above library
- If after it clone attempt of git-repo raised "urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError" error then remove certifi or use certifi from patch

**Longer more pure way**

- unpack library.zip
- replace urllib3 with 1.24.1 (download, compile, replace old *.pyo)
- replace dulwich with same content from https://github.com/dulwich/dulwich/, latest 0.19.11, (download, compile, replace old *.pyo)
- We have don't replace hg-git, because bundled hggit contains latest compatibility fixes for Mercurial 5 (while dmitriyse's version don't have yet)
- remove certify
- re-pack library

Comment: I had downloaded the patch and it somewhat worked in terms of migrating the mecurial to git but for some reason my branches have not copied over and im not sure why do I have recreate all those branches in the git repo from scratch or is there another way?

Comment: You need to give bookmark names to all your branches to have them in git repo, because mercurial developers and git developer mean different things by "branches".

Comment: @obratim - Yes, but `branch_bookmark_suffix` do it automagically, if defined