# Is it possible to have different Source Control Engines for individual projects?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, version-control

We have been using Mercurial/VisualHG as the default Source Control plug-in in VS 2017. Now, all new projects shall be dealt with using Git, but the old ones will continue to use Mercurial/HG until completely converted. The Source Control plug-in is a setting in the global settings of VS, but is it eventually possible to define the Source Control plug-ins for each project individually?

Comment: Just add git-support to core Mercurial with hg-git

Comment: @LazyBadger How can I do it? An example or a link to a reference would be great.

Comment: @LazyBadger With hg-git you can make your HG system to work with a Git repository, as far as I understand. This is certainly great, but is it still possible to let VS handle individual projects assigning different Version Control plugins? In my opinion, the answer is no. Any other answers?

Comment: If you use [HgVS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Multicoreware.HgVS), then you have THG (or pure Mercurial?) installed. You can enable|add [hg-git](https://hg-git.github.io/) extension to Mercurial, [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405634/abort-no-module-named-selectors-when-pushing-mercurial-repository-to-git-rep/57239579#57239579) in order to have working (for "fresh and previous" releases). Add repositories the same way as before, but prepend URLs of Git-repos with `git+` before protocol. Use *one common configuration* as you done it before

Comment: @FrancescaY - I know **nothing** (and even more than nothing) about VS and plugin per se