# Possible to define a different source control plug-in on a per-solution (or per-project) basis?

Tags: git, visual-studio, svn, version-control, visual-studio-2022

I'm mostly working with VisualSVN and sometimes with GitLab. My goal is to automatically let Visual Studio choose which source control plug-in to use when opening a solution.

[image]

Having read other questions here about changing the source control plug-in per solution like e.g.:

- [How to specify the source control plugin on a per-solution basis in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8307824/107625)
- [Is it possible to have different Source Control Engines for individual projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57645395/107625)
- [How to configure Visual Studio to use different source control providers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5994009/107625)

Seems that this is/was not possible for VS 2019 and older.

There is [an extension for Visual Studio 2017 that seems to be abandoned](https://github.com/ceztko/SccAutoSwitcher/issues/6).

Since currently Visual Studio 2022 is in preview and I found no way there either, I hope that Microsoft now includes a built-in way to do this that I didn't yet have discovered.

#### My question

Is there any way to configure on a per-solution-basis which source control plug-in to load?

Comment: Update approx. one year later: We moved 90 % of our actively worked-on projects to GitLab and never looked back ever since then .